# I can't seem to troubleshoot this error. HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

[image: The onclick button on the nav-bars isn't working.]

[image: this is the same code I used for my other pages but it just doesn't work on this page.]

[image]

I have tried copy and pasting the codes that work on the other pages because it on the other pages.

Comment: `nav-links` is the `class`, but you're trying to get the element by **ID**. You can use `document.querySelector(".nav-links")` instead. There's also no need to grab it twice if you're doing it outside the function. (and make sure the script is below the element). (Also, please post code, not images of code)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.getElementById('nav-links')` to find your element. However, this element is defined with `class="nav-links"` rather than `id="nav-links"`. There are two solutions:

1. Change the HTML code of your `div` to `<div id="nav-links">...</div>`. This has a potential to break your CSS code
2. Change the JS to search by class: `var show = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-links')[0];`

Also you can remove the definition on line 90 because `show` is already defined on line 85

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an element by ID when the element has no ID. Therefore, the variable you're trying to get properties from is null.

You can try changing your element from

```
<div class="nav-links">
```

To

```
<div id="nav-links">
```

Otherwise you'll need to select by class. I'd recommend changing the ID.